# Receber resposta OkHttp KOTLIN

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Estou tentando tratar os dados recebidos de uma API externa.

Tenho dois arquivos, um responsável por fazer a requisição, e o principal para chamar a função, porém não consigo passar o retorno dos dados para a tela principal.

Código de requisição, arquivo `HttpHelper.kt`:

```
 fun get(id : String) : String {

        // Definir url
        val URL = "http://192.168.100.58/api/puxar.php?id=${id}"

        // Criar um cliente que vai disparar a requisição
        val client = OkHttpClient()

        // criar uma requisição GET
        val request = Request.Builder().url(URL).get().build()

        // Enviar a requisicao para o servidor
        val response = client.newCall(request).execute()

        // Extrair o body da requisição
        val responseBody = response.body()
        
        println(responseBody!!.string())

        return responseBody.toString()

    }
```

Quando tento imprimir somente no console direto na função, ele me retorna os dados do `GET` corretamente:

```
"2021-06-17 09:56:21.673 22714-22838/com.example.api I/System.out: Usuario: robitaker"
```

Mas quando faço o `return` para o outro arquivo, me retorna assim:

```
"2021-06-17 09:56:21.673 22714-22838/com.example.api I/System.out: okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@e7cca09
"
```

O código que estou usando para chamar é esse no arquivo `ListaUsuarios.kt`:

```
package com.example.api

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import com.example.api.Http.HttpHelper
import org.jetbrains.anko.doAsync

class ListaUsuarios : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_usuarios)


        doAsync {

            val http = HttpHelper()


           val exibi = http.get("30")

            println(exibi)

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu método `get()`, você tá chamando dois métodos diferentes:

```
println(responseBody!!.string())

return responseBody.toString()
```

`string()` e `toString()`. O método `string()` retorna o corpo da resposta da sua requisição, que provavelmente é o que você quer (nesse exemplo, seria "Usuario: robitaker"). Já o método `toString()` retorna uma 'representação em String' de um objeto, que é essa string "estranha" por padrão, ou pode ser qualquer outra coisa se a classe `ResponseBody` tiver sobrescrito esse método - que, pelo jeito, não sobrescreveu. De qualquer forma, você não está interessado nesse valor aqui.

Então pra resolver o seu problema, basta chamar o método `string()` na hora de retornar o valor desse seu método. Ou melhor ainda, pra evitar esses tipos de problemas, use uma mesma variável tanto pra mostrar quanto pra retornar:

```
val response = responseBody!!.string()

println(response)

return response
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, deu certo !!!